# Android app to simply launch the Android task switcher without including itself in the task list

Tags: android, task-management

Can anyone recommend an [android](/questions/tagged/android) app that simply launches the ***Android task switcher*** without including itself in the list of tasks?

I want an app with this functionality so I can launch the ***Android task switcher*** from another tool, which has the limitation of only being able to launch apps (not shortcuts) that are selected from a list of all installed apps.

The closest I have found is [Recent Task 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaija.activityhistory2).  It works well, but its own task is always included in the task list, making it much less useful.

Must work on Android KitKat.

Either [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) or paid is fine, but gratis is always better.  Either [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) or closed-source is fine, but open-source is always better.

The recommended app must not have a service always running.  It must simply launch the Android task switcher, and then exit.

Comment: First thought "what's wrong with the most-recent-tab" until I realized your last paragraph: so calling an intent is no option. Not sure whether such an app exists; feel free taking a look at my app-list of [Task-Switchers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_taskswitcher#group_553) (I've never tried them myself recently; last time I've used one is ages ago under Android 2.x).

Comment: @Izzy The only way I could call an intent is if there is an app that does nothing more than call a customizable intent.  I used to have an app like that, but I do not recall what it was called, and I have not been able to find it via searches.

Comment: 's/tab/list/p' or 's/tab/button/p' – the button bringing up the list of recently-used apps :)

Comment: *LOL* [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) regexp replaces. Translation: "replace "tab" by either "list" or "button". Interpretation: in the first comment, read "what's wrong with the most-recent-button/list" – the button one normally presses/touches to bring up that list. Clear now? #D

Comment: Yeah, for geeks that's like "SMS lingo", very frequently used in IRC. So 's/.*//g'? Ahem: Shall we remove all those comments? #D